# optimise sql function to get common elements

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a function that takes two delimited strings and returns the number of common elements. The

The main code of the function is (@intCount is the expected return value)

```
    SET @commonCount = (select count(*) from (
    select token from dbo.splitString(@userKeywords, ';')
    intersect
    select token from dbo.splitString(@itemKeywords, ';')) as total)
```

where splitString uses a while loop and charIndex to split a string into delimited tokens and inserts it into a table.

The problem I am having is that this only processes at a speed of about 100 rows per second and by the size of my dataset, this will take about 8-10 days to finish.

The size of the two strings may be upto 1500 characters in length.

Is there anyway I can achieve this fast enough to be usable?

Comment: Is this something that you need to run all the time, or is it a one-time effort?

Comment: i'm running some simulations for data mining so need to do this whenever my model changes or if I want to experiment with new formulae. probably not very frequent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance problem is probably the combination of a cursor (for the while loop) and the user defined function.

If one of these strings is constant (such as item key words), you can search for each one independently:

```
select *
from users u
where charindex(';'+<item1>+';', ';'+u.keywords) > 0
union all
select *
from users u
where charindex(';'+<item2>+';', ';'+u.keywords) > 0 union all
```

Alternatively, a set based approach can work, but you have to normalize the data (plug here for having data in the right format to begin with).  That is, you want a table that has:

```
userid
keyword
```

And another that has

```
itemid
keyword
```

(if there are different types of items.  Otherwise this is just a list of keywords.)

Then your query would look like:

```
select *
from userkeyword uk join
     itemkeyword ik
     on uk.keyword = ik.keyword
```

And the SQL engine would perform its magic.

Now, how can you create such a list?  If you have only a handful of key words per user, then you can do something like:

```
with keyword1 as (select u.*, charindex(';', keywords) as pos1,
                         left(keywords, charindex(';', keywords)-1) as keyword1
                  from user u
                  where charindex(';', keywords) > 0
                 ),
     keyword2 as (select u.*, charindex(';', keywords, pos1+1) as pos2,
                         left(keywords, charindex(';', keywords)-1, pos1+1) as keyword2
                  from user u
                  where charindex(';', keywords, pos1+2) > 0
                 ),
        ...
select userid, keyword1
from keyword1
union all
select userid, keyword2
from keyword2
...
```

To get the maximum number of elements in the itemKeyWords, you can use the following query:

```
select max(len(Keywords) - len(replace(Keywords, ';', '')))
from user
```

Comment: I'm thinking of going in the table based approach. The data that i got was in flat  files in the format that I uploaded them to the tables. They werent normalized and are about 2-3 gigs in size

Comment: I would use powershell to split the data, and then load it in a normalized format.  If you already have the data in a table, try the approach in the email.  It might work better than you expect, especially if you are running on a multiprocessor machine.  Your original approach is probably serializing the query, so it is not taking advantage of all your hardware.